# how to assign a function return value in storedprocedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a function  **ufnGetTVP**  and needs to assign the return value to a table variable in stored procedure.

I have tried the below code but getting error. I couldnt find any relevant articles to fix this issue.

```
create proc testfunc( @input varchar(50))
as 
begin
DECLARE @mt TABLE
set  @mt = select * from ufnGetTVP(@input)

end
```

It will be helpful , if someone could identify what goes wrong here.

Comment: may be you can use your function without a temp table. what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried inserting into the variable?

Also declare the columns on your table to match the function:

```
DECLARE @mt TABLE (Column1 INT, Column2 Int...)

INSERT INTO @mt
SELECT Column1, Column2, ... FROM ufnGetTVP(@input)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Temp tables also, You don't have to worry about column definitions.

```
create proc testfunc( @input varchar(50))
as 
begin

    select * into #temp from ufnGetTVP(@input)

    select * from #temp

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL drop table #temp

end
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include the structure of the table you are declaring:

```
DECLARE @mt as TABLE
(
    <columns list>
)
```

Second, you can't use `set`, you need to use `insert`:

```
INSERT INTO @mt (<columns list>)
SELECT <columns list> FROM dbo.ufnGetTVP(@input)
```